# How to enable treat warnings as errors in Unreal Engine 4.24?

Tags: unreal-4

I've had little luck googling and it takes about an hour to build the engine (which I have to do if I'm to test if it works), so guessing is a bit time consuming.

I've seen advice to add the `'/WX'` flag to `*.target.cs`, as well to one of the functions in `VCToolChain.cs`, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Has anyone here enabled this and knows how it works? I don't think it matters, but I've been using VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

## Assumptions

- You're building the Unreal Engine from the github source.
- You're on Windows 10.
- Instructions from **Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition** are similar to those for **VS2017**.

## Solution

The advice you got regarding [**/WX** option is correct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-160), but I don't think the ***.target.cs** file was the proper place to put it. I see hints that there is a variable to append additional command-line options in that file, but nothing solid. Also, since there are multiple targets that you can build, I figured the following is the safest way to go.

### Steps

1. Open the solution, **UE4.sln**.
2. Right-click on the project **UE4 > Properties**.
   [image]
3. Go to **Configuration Properties > NMake > Additional Options**.
4. Append **/WX** to the list of options already there.
   [image]
5. Press **Okay** and rerun your build.

Hope that solves your problem!

## Additional Notes

The solution here configures **msbuild** to build the Unreal Engine binaries. Once you have those binaries build, the **Unreal Build Tool (UBT)** binary is used to build your UE-specific code (instead of msbuild). The configured **UBT command** treats warnings-as-errors by default.

## References

[MSVC Compiler Options > Warning Levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-160)

[Understanding Unreal Build Tool](https://ericlemes.com/2018/11/23/understanding-unreal-build-tool/)

Comment: This doesn't work. The Additional Options there are for Intellisense, not nmake as you can just about make out in the explanation text in the screenshot: 'Specifies additional compiler switches to be used by Intellisense when parsing C++ files'.  There must be some way to pass these additional parameters, but I haven't found it yet.